# how to output coefficients of multinomial regression with emmeans?

Tags: r, emmeans

```
ml <- foreign::read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
model.fit <- multinom(ses~female*prog+read, data=ml)
```

I have the following coefficients:

```
Call:
multinom(formula = ses ~ female * prog + read, data = ml)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept) femalefemale progacademic progvocation       read femalefemale:progacademic
middle   -1.919435  -0.01626812     1.271990     1.301494 0.04404166                 -1.334239
high     -4.701536   0.44126239     2.092619     1.171212 0.07779108                 -1.815047
       femalefemale:progvocation
middle                -0.6859539
high                  -1.5431251

Residual Deviance: 386.2441 
AIC: 414.2441
```

with odds ratio `exp(1.271990)=3.567946` and `exp(2.092619)=8.106117`

However, with emmeans package,

```
EMM <- emmeans(model.fit, revpairwise~ses|female*prog)
REMM <- regrid(EMM, transform="logit")
contrast(REMM, interaction="revpairwise", type="response", by="female")
```

I can only get the following output

```
female = male:
 ses_revpairwise prog_revpairwise    odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
 middle / low    academic / general       4.926  5.380 14    1   1.460  0.1663
 high / low      academic / general      15.314 16.723 14    1   2.499  0.0255
 high / middle   academic / general       3.109  3.174 14    1   1.111  0.2853
 middle / low    vocation / general       7.385  9.044 14    1   1.633  0.1248
 high / low      vocation / general       4.430  5.496 14    1   1.200  0.2501
 high / middle   vocation / general       0.600  0.780 14    1  -0.393  0.7002
 middle / low    vocation / academic      1.499  1.699 14    1   0.357  0.7262
 high / low      vocation / academic      0.289  0.326 14    1  -1.099  0.2903
 high / middle   vocation / academic      0.193  0.222 14    1  -1.431  0.1745

female = female:
 ses_revpairwise prog_revpairwise    odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
 middle / low    academic / general       0.885  0.826 14    1  -0.131  0.8977
 high / low      academic / general       1.475  1.429 14    1   0.401  0.6943
 high / middle   academic / general       1.667  1.645 14    1   0.517  0.6130
 middle / low    vocation / general       3.075  3.245 14    1   1.065  0.3051
 high / low      vocation / general       0.656  0.750 14    1  -0.369  0.7177
 high / middle   vocation / general       0.213  0.262 14    1  -1.259  0.2287
 middle / low    vocation / academic      3.475  3.327 14    1   1.301  0.2144
 high / low      vocation / academic      0.445  0.446 14    1  -0.808  0.4324
 high / middle   vocation / academic      0.128  0.135 14    1  -1.947  0.0719

Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

The ORs are different: 4.926 vs 3.567946 & 15.314 vs 8.106117.

What's going on here?

same output as exp of multinom coefficients

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time preparing an answer, and see no evidence that you have read it. Is it useful? If so, I'd appreciate your accepting it or at least upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients of multinomial models are NOT odds ratios. They are on the log scale, not the logit scale.

I will demonstrate using manual calculations with model predictions.
First, create a grid with the factor combinations. We also set `read` equal to its mean, which is 52.23.

```r
G = expand.grid(female = c("male", "female"), 
                prog = c("general", "academic", "vocation"), 
                read = 52.23)
```

Now, let's obtain the predicted probabilities on this grid:

```r
( probs = predict(model.fit, newdata = G, type = "probs") )
##          low    middle      high
## 1 0.33426672 0.4892138 0.1765194
## 2 0.30666233 0.4415713 0.2517663
## 3 0.09521526 0.4971990 0.4075858
## 4 0.29097972 0.3937028 0.3153175
## 5 0.12373582 0.6654763 0.2107879
## 6 0.23636138 0.6298578 0.1337808
```

From these, we convert these probabilities to odds:

```r
( odds = probs / (1 - probs) )
##         low    middle      high
## 1 0.5021031 0.9577664 0.2143578
## 2 0.4422987 0.7907390 0.3364809
## 3 0.1052353 0.9888583 0.6880081
## 4 0.4103969 0.6493561 0.4605310
## 5 0.1412084 1.9893246 0.2670865
## 6 0.3095199 1.7016644 0.1544422
```

Finally, we obtain ratios of these odds, and combine with `G` to show the associated factor levels:

```r
( OR = cbind(G, rat21 = odds[,2]/odds[,1], rat31 = odds[,3]/odds[,1]) )
##   female     prog  read     rat21     rat31
## 1   male  general 52.23  1.907510 0.4269199
## 2 female  general 52.23  1.787794 0.7607550
## 3   male academic 52.23  9.396644 6.5378090
## 4 female academic 52.23  1.582264 1.1221600
## 5   male vocation 52.23 14.087868 1.8914355
## 6 female vocation 52.23  5.497754 0.4989734
```

None of the above calculations used the **emmeans** package; just model predictions. So now we verify that we obtain the same results using `emmeans()`. First, create the `emmGrid` object for the same factor combinations:

```r
emm = emmeans(model.fit, ~ ses | female * prog)
```

Then, obtain Dunnett contrasts of these estimates after re-gridding to the logit scale:

```r
contrast(regrid(emm, "logit"), "dunnett", type = "resp")
## female = male, prog = general:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low      1.908  1.617 14    1   0.762  0.6702
##  high / low        0.427  0.367 14    1  -0.990  0.5294
## 
## female = female, prog = general:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low      1.788  1.371 14    1   0.758  0.6726
##  high / low        0.761  0.611 14    1  -0.340  0.9075
## 
## female = male, prog = academic:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low      9.397  6.486 14    1   3.246  0.0112
##  high / low        6.538  4.473 14    1   2.744  0.0299
## 
## female = female, prog = academic:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low      1.582  0.816 14    1   0.890  0.5902
##  high / low        1.122  0.579 14    1   0.223  0.9542
## 
## female = male, prog = vocation:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low     14.088 12.602 14    1   2.957  0.0198
##  high / low        1.891  1.688 14    1   0.714  0.6996
## 
## female = female, prog = vocation:
##  contrast     odds.ratio     SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  middle / low      5.498  4.363 14    1   2.148  0.0914
##  high / low        0.499  0.423 14    1  -0.820  0.6339
## 
## P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 2 tests 
## Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

These results are the same as the `OR` matrix obtained earlier, verifying that `emmeans()` is doing things correctly. Note that none of these odds ratios are equal to 3.567946 or 8.106117. That's because the regression coefficients are *not* logs of odds ratios.

I'll demonstrate just one of the cases to show how it works. Consider the first case, where `female = "male"`, `program = "general"`, and `read = 52.53`. Here, only the intercept and coefficient of `read` are relevant, as the dummy variables for everything else are zero. We have two rows of coefficients, for `middle` and `high`; those for `low` are all considered zero. We thus have the following linear predictor for the multinomial response:

```r
coef(model.fit)
##        (Intercept) femalefemale progacademic progvocation       read ...
## middle   -1.919435  -0.01626812     1.271990     1.301494 0.04404166 ...
## high     -4.701536   0.44126239     2.092619     1.171212 0.07779108 ...

( lp = c(lo = 0, 
         mid = -1.919435 + 0.04404166 * 52.23, 
         hi = -4.701536 + 0.07779108 * 52.53) )
##         lo        mid         hi 
##  0.0000000  0.3808609 -0.6151706
```

As mentioned, the linear predictions are on the log scale. To back-transform them, we exponentiate them, then divide by the sum so that they sum to 1:

```r
exp(lp) / sum(exp(lp))
##        lo       mid        hi 
## 0.3328792 0.4871834 0.1799374
```

Note that these are the same (with slight baubles from rounding) as the first row of `prob` that we obtained from `predict()`. Considering how this works, **if** there were only two levels of the multinomial response, then the linear predictor will be of the form `c(0, b)`, and the probability for the second level will be `exp(b) / (1 + exp(b))` so that `b` is indeed a logit. But that's only true for two multinomial classes.

Also, a comment that it is unclear why the OP chose the coefficients of `progacademic` and not, say, the intercepts. Nor is it clear why interaction contrasts were selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry, I should make this more clear. What I want to calculate is the ratio of ratio, controlling for sex.
For example, I would like to know the ratio of ratio (high relative to low) between academic and general of among males
This is something like Difference in Difference model. I am trying to firgure out the slope before the intervention and the slope after the intervention.

Comment: @gokart This question is vastly different from the one that was asked. And really, both questions are about interpretation. ofmodel fits, not computing, so they really should be on CrossValidated instead of StackOverflow.